# multiple excel if statements to produce value 1,2 or 3

Tags: excel, if-statement

I am trying to find out the right if statement to use for this task:

```
if B5 is higher than C5 = 1
if B5 is within 2% higher than C5 = 2
if B5 is lower than C5 = 3
```

I have the formula for the second statement

```
=IF(AND(B5>(C5-(C5*2/100)),B5<(C5+(C5*2/100))),"yes","no")
```

Im just not sure how to put it into one statement to get one of the 3 numbers to come out at the end. main thing im struggling with is that there are only two answers in an excel if statement it can return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to make sure I understand correctly, when B5 is within 2% of C5 (either greater than, equal to, or less than), should the formula return "2"?  If so, you can use the following formula:

```
=IF(ABS(B5-C5)<=C5*0.02,2,IF(B5>C5,1,3))
```

This formula returns "2" when B5 is exactly 2% less than or exactly 2% greater than C5.  If you want it to return "3" and "1" in these cases respectively, you can use the following instead:

```
=IF(ABS(B5-C5)<C5*0.02,2,IF(B5>C5,1,3))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can nest IF formulae:

```
=IF(condition2, 2, IF(condition1, 1, IF(condition3, 3, "error!")))
```

With your conditions, it looks something like:

```
=IF(AND(B5>(C5-(C5*2/100)), B5<(C5+(C5*2/100))), 2, IF(B5>C5, 1, 3))
```

Answer (score -2):

I haven't used excel for years, so I'm not sure as to the exact syntax, but you can you nested if-else statements to achieve this sort of thing. i.e. something to the effect of:

```
if (B5 is within 2% higher than C5)
    print 2
else if (B5 is higher than C5)
    print 1
else
    print 3
```