# Multiple IF Formulas

Tags: excel

I need to link numbers to text so I can trigger conditional formatting for Icon sets. In the simplest way possible I need to link like this.

```
Minor = 1
Medium = 2
Urgent = 3
```

The text is selected from a dropdown via data validation. I need to tag a number to the list item and send the number to the cell next to it so I can trigger conditional formatting.

The only issue is, I'm not to well veresed on Excel any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Heres what I have thus far.

```
=IF(F7<>"Minor","1","0",IF(F7<>"Medium","2","0",IF(F7<>"Urgent","3","0")))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [multiple excel if statements to produce value 1,2 or 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5276201/multiple-excel-if-statements-to-produce-value-1-2-or-3)

Comment: Did my answer work for you? If so then please mark as correct by clicking the grey/green check mark by the answer. It is something only you can do.

Comment: It did, sorry I can get rather busy at times but I'll always return to amend my questions. Don't worry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
=IF(F7="Minor",1,0)+IF(F7="Medium",2,0)+IF(F7="Urgent",3,0)
```

The correct way to "nest" the if statement is this:

```
=IF(F7="Minor",1,IF(F7="Medium",2,IF(F7="Urgent",3,0)))
```

---

**If you have the latest version of Excel 365 or are using the online version then:**

You can use either:

```
=IFERROR(IFS(F7="Minor",1,F7="Medium",2,F7="Urgent",3),0)
```

Or, since you are referencing the same cell in each you can use:

```
=IFERROR(SWITCH(F7, "Minor", 1, "Medium", 2, "Urgent", 3), 0)
```

Comment: Thanks for your elegant solution. Fits the request perfectly! :)

Comment: @Null glad to help, please come back in 10 minutes to mark as correct.

Comment: After having mentioned the [IFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFS-function-36329a26-37b2-467c-972b-4a39bd951d45), I'm surprized you omitted the [SWITCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SWITCH-function-47ab33c0-28ce-4530-8a45-d532ec4aa25e). e.g. `=IFERROR(SWITCH(F7, "minor", 1, "medium", 2, "urgent", 3), "")` [sample](http://i.stack.imgur.com/7MDFv.png)

Comment: @Jeeped I missed that one, I did not realize they moved it from vba to worksheet function.  I hope you don't mind me adding it to the answer above for future reference.

Comment: No worries. I'm currently using [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/What-s-new-in-Excel-2016-for-Windows-5fdb9208-ff33-45b6-9e08-1f5cdb3a6c73) as my 'table of contents' for xl2016 (while I suppress my disappointment on not having the new functions in the desktop version).